# Solve non-linear equation with MS Solver Foundation C#

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

**Context**

I would like to solve the following equation using C# algorithms, and do not want to reinvent the wheel. I examined Math.NET, and quickly turned out it only supports solving liner matrix equations with numeric methods. Searching toward I concluded that using MS Solve Foundation I can write C# code to solve my equation with some numerical method.

**Question**

Given the

`a^x + b^x + c^x = 1`

equation, where a, b, c are given constants, for 
example 0.4, 0.35, 0.5.  Unfortunately all MS Solver Foundation examples are optimization and problem solving, and not simple non-linear equation solving, so I do not even know what method to use, what method is suitable at all, and what are the options.

Could anyone point what are my options?

Answer (score 1):

My bad.

I figured out that my problem is not "solving" or "solve" instead it is "root-finding".

Looking for those words it turned out that Math.NET has 8 different method to do that.
Decided to leave the question here (along with this answer) instead deleting, but I am open to delete in case of close votes.